# setting up JavaFX 15 having errors

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, configuration

I'm using visual studio code for my IDE. I was having trouble setting up JavaFX 15.0.1; I have java 14.0.2. I'm using the latest version of VSC.

When trying to run the code I was getting the run-time error, "components missing..." but now getting I am getting the error

> **Error: Could not find or load main class Lib.javafx-sdk-15.0.1.lib   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Lib.javafx-sdk-15.0.1.lib.**

File location of the project: D:\ServerAPI\helloWorld

File location for the JavaFX jar files: E:\Java Lib\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib

I'm fairly new to programming so any explanation would be deeply appreciated.

This is the code I used from github to test it.

```
        package serverAPI;


       import javafx.application.Application;
       import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
       import javafx.event.EventHandler;
       import javafx.scene.Scene;
       import javafx.scene.control.Button;
       import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
       import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
    public class App extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
           StackPane root = new StackPane();
           root.getChildren().add(btn);
           primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
           primaryStage.show();
       }
      }
```

This is the launch.Json configuration I edited in VSC:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path E:/Java Lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "serverAPI.App",
            "projectName": "helloWorld_8408fb31"
        },
    ]
}
```

I don't know any other details that I should put in here.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is in your json file. on the vmArgs line:

> "vmArgs": "--module-path E:/Java Lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",

You can't have a space in the path. So you need to move this library to a location that doesn't include a space in the path.